# Manipulating Service Response but returns undefined

Tags: json, angular, angular-services

Models component:

```
import { Component, OnInit, AfterContentInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Model } from '../model';
import { EdmundsAPIService } from '../edmunds-api.service';
import {  ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-models',
  templateUrl: './models.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./models.component.css']
})
export class ModelsComponent implements OnInit, AfterContentInit {
public models: Model[];
errorMessage: string;

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute,
              private _EdmundsAPIService: EdmundsAPIService) {}

  getModels(): void {
    this._EdmundsAPIService.getModels(this.route.snapshot.params[ 'data' ])
      .subscribe(
       models => this.models = models,
       error =>  this.errorMessage = <any>error);
     }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getModels();
    console.log(this.models);
  }
```

EdmundsAPIService:

```
  getModels(makeNiceName: number): Observable<Model[]> {
    return this.http.get('REDACTED')
    .map(res => res.json())
    .catch(this.handleError);
  }
```

I am trying to access 'this.models' in my ngOnInit (or other lifecycle hook) in order to sort and filter my JSON response. However my `console.log` returns `undefined`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
getModels(): void {
    this._EdmundsAPIService.getModels(this.route.snapshot.params[ 'data' ])
      .subscribe(
           (models: Model[]) => { 
               this.models = models

               //THIS IS WHERE YOU MANIPULATE YOUR DATA
               console.log(this.models) // IF SERVICE IS WORKING THIS WILL NOT BE UNDEFINED
           },
           (error: any) =>  this.errorMessage = error 
      );
 }
```

Comment: I tried to add the following below `console.log`:    `    for (vari = 0; this.models.models.length; i++) {
      console.log(this.models.models[i]); }`

I'm getting errors

Answer (score 1):

This is an asyncronous call, at the time you try to `console.log` the result, the data has not yet been retrieved.

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.getModels(); // executing
    // logging before above function has finished executing
    console.log(this.models);
  }
```

If you would move your `console.log` inside the subscription, then you would be sure that you have the values:

```
  getModels(): void {
    this._EdmundsAPIService.getModels(this.route.snapshot.params[ 'data' ])
      .subscribe(
       models =>  {
         this.models = models; // values set
         console.log(this.models); // values available!
       });
     }
```

Comment: I am sure I have the values, this is not the issue. The console.log was a 'test function' to retrieve the values. What I am trying to do is get the JSON response -> put it in models object which I can sort, filter, and manipulate in my component.

Comment: in other words, just like we can access {{data | json}} in the html template, I would like to manipulate it in my ts component. Maybe I cannot do that in the component, that's fine, I don't mind storing it in my html template and doing pure javascript JSON manipulation

Comment: Of course you can manipulate it in your component. Do you need to do something instantly or do just want it rendered in view as a starting point?

Comment: The JSON response comes with a 'categories' property which is nested in child objects within the model object. Ideally, if I can manipulate it in my component, I would like to store this async response in a variable (preferably models: Model[] - an object I have defined through a class) and using 'models' I would like to use nested for loops to iterate through the array meticulously. By extracting the categories property and placing it in an unfiltered array, I plan to filter it by uniqueness (no duplicates!), THEN using this NEW filtered array, I plan to use an *ngFor to build buttons.